# React Typescript How to add a new array to an array of objects useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I there! I'm using typescript in my React project. Now I want to create a useState of array of objects but I have a important error when I want to add a new record. How Can add a new value to my useState? Thanks!

```
    // interfaces.type.ts
export interface ManagementDocuments {
  id: number;
  idDocument: number;
  name: string;

// shippers.tsx
const [shipperManagementDocumentsSelected, setShipperManagementDocumentsSelected] = useState<ManagementDocuments[]>([]);

const inputChangeHandler = (name, newValue): any => {
    switch (name) {
      case DocumentType.MANAGEMENT:
        // the problem starts here, I don't know how to add a new record to my useState
        setShipperManagementDocumentsSelected(
          ...shipperManagementDocuments,
          newValue

        );
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `newValue`, an array or an object? If it's an array, is it an array of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
setShipperManagementDocumentsSelected(prev => {
   return [ 
      ...prev,
      newValue
   ]
);
```

Here is the documentation for setState

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: His state is an array.

Comment: Wops, updated! :)

Comment: Thank you very very much!